# Time period changed when selecting calendar on Saturday

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a different time period on Saturday compare with another day time period. E.g. Monday to Friday, time only can select from 8:30 to 5:30 and Saturday only allow 8:30 to 12:30. After done the calendar, I don't know how to continue it. Anyone can please help?

```html
<div class="col-5 col-12-xsmall">
  <label>Date</label>
</div>
<div class="col-5 col-12-xsmall">
  <input type="text" id="flatpickr" name="date" placeholder="Select Date" />
</div>
<!--Appointment Time-->
<div class="col-5 col-12-xsmall">
  <label>Time</label>
</div>
<div class="col-5 col-12-xsmall">
    <select class="form-control" name="time" id="time">
        <option value="Select Time" >- Select Time -</option>
         <option value="08:30 AM">08:30 AM</option>
         <option value="08:45 AM">08:45 AM</option>

         <option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
         <option value="09:15 AM">09:15 AM</option>
          <option value="09:30 AM">09:30 AM</option>
          <option value="09:45 AM">09:45 AM</option>

          <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
          <option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
          <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
          <option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>

          <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
          <option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
          <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
          <option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>

          <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
          <option value="12:15 PM">12:15 PM</option>
          <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
          <option value="12:45 PM">12:45 PM</option>

          <option value="01:00 PM">01:00 PM</option>
          <option value="01:15 PM">01:15 PM</option>
          <option value="01:30 PM">01:30 PM</option>
           <option value="01:45 PM">01:45 PM</option>

           <option value="02:00 PM">02:00 PM</option>
           <option value="02:15 PM">02:15 PM</option>
           <option value="02:30 PM">02:30 PM</option>
           <option value="02:45 PM">02:45 PM</option>

</select>
</div>
```

Below is the script

```
<script>
var example = flatpickr('#flatpickr',{
altInput: true;
altFormat: "I, F j, Y;
dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
minDate: new Date().fp_incr(+1),
"disable": [
function(date) {
  return (date.getDay() === 0);
}
],
  "locale": {
"firstDayOfWeek": 1
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you only use flatpickr on the date input or do you use it for the time input as well?

Comment: I didn't use for the time input because the design of the time layout from flatpickr is not I  wanted, I would prefer to have the dropdown of the time selected manually.

Comment: So it's just a regular text input, no special handling?

Comment: Sorry my mistake to make you feel confusing. I have re-edit the code. When I select Saturday on flatpickr calendar, the dropdown time only show 08:30am to 12:30pm. So when I select Mon to Fri, the dropdown time show 08:30am to 02:45pm. How do I write the code in php or javavscript?

Comment: You can define an [onChange hook](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/#hooks) for your datepicker and inside it you can simply disable or remove any options whose values are over 12:30.

Comment: Still don't have idea how to do

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Defining the hook? Selecting the options you want to add/remove? Doing the actual adding/removing? P.S. Where do those values come from? Are they hardcoded or do they come from a database or a file?

Comment: The time select is a hardcore. Totally don't have any idea how to define using the onchange to change the time period if selected saturday.

Comment: It's no different than any other `onChange` handler. My suggestion: 1) add a class to all times that are only applicable to workdays; 2) fetch all the options by that class; 3) iterate them and set their `disabled` property based on which day was selected. See [here](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#properties) how to get the selected date inside the picker.